# Error de compilación en templates

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy intentado aplicar templates a un vector. El problema es que el compilador me muestra un error en la línea 23, lo tengo señalizado con un comentario en el código, el error es el siguiente: **no member named 'allocate' in 'vector_base >**; y la verdad es que no lo entiendo, ¿por qué no me deja acceder a la función allocate? Compilador utilizado: clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct allocator {
    void allocate(size_t s) {

    }
};

template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
struct vector_base {
    A alloc;
};

template <class T, typename A = vector_base<T>>
class vector
{
    vector_base<T,A> vector_ptr;
    public:
    void reserve(size_t newalloc) {
      vector_ptr.alloc.allocate(4); // error
    }
};


int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu plantilla `vector` tiene dos parámetros plantilla:

- `T` el tipo almacenado.
- `A` el alojador de memoria (*allocator*).

El alojador, tiene como parámetro por defecto `vector_base`, el cual no es un alojador. Seguramente [querías hacer esto](https://tio.run/##fZDNasMwEITveoqFXiJInUN7ql2B38H3oChLKtAf0tohLXl2V/hPSQ/VScws38yuCuH1otQ4vminTH9GaLRPFFFawYomzcVHTV9PokXr400wRmiDkZQlZWRK0AmWEb0ikMZ4JclH@GGQ3@D1eRVxl/Q3HgkSz@5k39m9fsTRLaCTFqHbw/Zv4bNwm05sYQOqrBxPMuES186D9R/s0vJf5jwzI9lSvvCbbt@KVQgU62kg9Cej1UfZNGLCOGyLOrxOIXypBw@EanKq7TbvvIbDATDGnF9uw7QjsFK7HX9q1WQ9F5p7DNUa/Mbz7uP4Cw):

```
template <class T, typename A = allocator<T>>
//                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Alojador de memoria, no vector.
class vector
{
    vector_base<T,A> vector_ptr;
    public:
    void reserve(size_t newalloc) {
      vector_ptr.alloc.allocate(4);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

El compilador te indica que el miembro que quieres acceder no existe, lo que no esta claro en tu ejemplo es el tipo de `alloc`. Suponiendo que es de tipo `std::vector`, deberías usar `alloc.get_allocator().allocate(4)`

Comment: Los miembros de allocator son públicos, ¿para qué querría utilizar un getter?